# How to receive exception when Amqp fails to connect?

Tags: javascript, amqp

```js
const amqp = require('amqp-connection-manager')

const {CONNECTION_URL} = require('./config/env')

class AmqpConnectionService {

  async openConnection() {
    this.connection = await amqp.connect([CONNECTION_URL])
    this.channelWrapper = await this.connection.createChannel({setup(channel) {}})

    await this.channelWrapper.waitForConnect()
  }
```

With this code when the `CONNECTION_URL` is a wrong URL then the code get stuck on the `waitForConnect()`.